# layout centering all the elements automatically

Tags: android, layout

I have three edit text fields and I will hide second and third edit text in my to create () and I want to show first edit text in the center and if first edit text is valid then I will UN hide the second edit text and now I want to align first edit text and second edit text should be centered in layout.... so on vice versa

Comment: in my oncreate method

Comment: share your layout xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 android:gravity="center"
```

Use this in the parent layout to center the elements

OR

You can use

```
  android:layout_gravity="center"
```

in the element to center in its parent.

And for hiding the EditText, pls use

```
  android:visibility="gone"
```

so that it doesn't take space in the layout

Answer (score 1):

try this layout `

```
<RelativeLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:hint="first edit text"/>
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:hint="second edit text"/>
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:hint="second edit text"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>`
```

and then hide the edit texts which you want to hide in the java code